# filtering document in mongoose based on id and one specific property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

just stuck on how to filter the below document on the basis of user_id and popupsArray.isSeen = true.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gxh0.png)

I want to get the popups from popupsArray whose isSeen = FALSE

Comment: Can you share the schema details and add in the question code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. We do recommend not to post image, instead of it, you need to post your code in snippets. You can simply use the `$filter in aggregation`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      popupsArray: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$popupsArray",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.isSeen",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NTMNShfPLhx)**